# How can I abstract dependent type from base C# base project using microsoft identity framework?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, code-reuse

I have an authentication project that I would like to reuse.

I have a AspNetCore Identity project called authentication which is intended to be a reusable authentication project. If you have looked at the AspNetCore Identity implementation you will see a type called UserManager where the application user is the class that you store your implementation of the user in the AspNetUsers database table.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

The problem I am having is that there is a controller in this isolated authentication project called AccountController which holds all the logging in/out, registering, and other related account actions. I wish to abstract the application user out of this project's class so I can change it based on the needs of the project for multiple solutions.

The authentication project has a startup class which is initiated as follows from within the project in which it is being used:

```
authenticationStartUp.ConfigureServices<ApplicationUser, MyDatabase>
      (services, Configuration);
```

As you can see, the subscribing project adds its own implementation of the ApplicationUser. Next, comes the configuration of the identity which references the TApplicationUser in the services.AddIdentity call.

```
    public void ConfigureServices<TApplicationUser, TContext>
          (IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationRoot Configuration)
        where TApplicationUser : IdentityUser
        where TContext : DbContext
    {
        services.AddIdentity<TApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<TContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Unfortunately, this now breaks down in the AccountController which is using the injected service. How, can the TApplicationUser be added to the controller.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<TApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public AccountController(UserManager<TApplicationUser> userManager) 
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
}
```

This is obviously broken since there is no TApplicationUser. Furthermore, if I add the TApplicationUser as follows the controller is nolonger resolved and nothing happens.

```
public class AccountController<TApplicationUser> : Controller 
   where TApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    private readonly UserManager<TApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public AccountController(UserManager<TApplicationUser> userManager) 
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to get application controller to still be resolved with the included type parameters?

And also, I have found another problem in that even if I add the type parameter in the base class how will I be able to add the type parameter in the views that use TApplicationUser. Here is an example

**View embedded in authentication project**

```
@* TApplicationUser obviously doesn't resolve *@
@inject SignInManager<TApplicationUser> SignInManager 
 @{
    var loginProviders = SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemes().ToList();
    if (loginProviders.Count == 0)
    {
        <div>
            <p>
                There are no external authentication services configured. See <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715">this article</a>
                for details on setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services.
            </p>
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            <div>
                <p>
                    @foreach (var provider in loginProviders)
                    {
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="provider" value="@provider.AuthenticationScheme" title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">@provider.AuthenticationScheme</button>
                    }
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
    }
}
```

Comment: Have the generic controller as a base controller

Comment: And what shall I pass as the basecontroller type parameter?

Comment: The application user from the using project

Comment: Currently, the AccountController lives in the authentication project so that won't be possible. Maybe if I undo that I can just have all the implementation living in the authentication project as a base class and inherit from each implementation passing the ApplicationUser as you stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the generic controller as a base controller that lives in the reusable project

```
public abstract class AccountControllerBase<TApplicationUser> : Controller 
    where TApplicationUser : IdentityUser {
    protected readonly UserManager<TApplicationUser> _userManager;

    protected AccountController(UserManager<TApplicationUser> userManager) {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
}
```

The using class/project would derive from the base controller and define the generic argument

```
public class AccountController : AccountControllerBase<ApplicationUser> {

    public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager) 
        : base(userManager) {  }

}
```

Comment: This does work but there is one small issue in that the RazorView is using @inject SignInManager<obviously no type parameter here> SignInManager. Is there  a way to solve this limitation. Since the signin manager is being used in the views?

Comment: Ok you'll have to clarify that part for me. Why and how is the manager being used in the view? The controller populates a ViewModel and passes that to the view so I am not totally clear on what you mean.

Comment: I updated the original post with some of the code. This code comes with the Microsoft Identity implementation I am using.

Comment: Reading it now. At first glance I would refactor the view to not depend on a generic. I would move that down one layer and have class inherit from the generic manager

Comment: I am not sure I understand exactly how to implement it the way you have described. I have created a helper class that sets the needed data to properties and added that helper to the ViewBag. This should work until I come across views that also depend on the SignInManager/UserManager TApplicationUser type. I haven't gotten there yet.